# ImportError: No module named vaderSentiment

Tags: python-2.7

I'm trying to run a code in python2.7 on windows os that uses sentiment analysis

```
from vaderSentiment.vaderSentiment import SentimentIntensityAnalyzer
analyzer = SentimentIntensityAnalyzer()
```

and I'm getting this error

```
ImportError: No module named vaderSentiment
```

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: `from vaderSentiment import SentimentIntensityAnalyzer` just use this

Answer (score 4):

Assuming you solved this one as it's from 7 months ago, but for anyone else searching for it:

Go into terminal/cmd and paste the following:

```
pip install vaderSentiment
```

More info on VADER: https://github.com/cjhutto/vaderSentiment

Answer (score 1):

```
from vaderSentiment.vaderSentiment import SentimentIntensityAnalyzer
    #note: depending on how you installed (e.g., using source code download versus pip install), you may need to import like this:
    #from vaderSentiment import SentimentIntensityAnalyzer
```

read the comment in a code

Answer (score 0):

Try running your file with Python3 instead of just python. Sometimes when you have  different pips/pythons installed on your computer you might have vaderSentiment installed in python2 when you need to run it in python3.

Answer (score 0):

Try to install **nltk** library from file jupyter, and try too import it in this way, This is how it worked for me:

```
from nltk.sentiment.vader import SentimentIntensityAnalyzer
```